# Selenium/Java reading CSV file using open csv

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, csv-file

```
UserName,Password
User1,Pwd1
User2,Pwd1
User3,Pwd3
```

Assume there is a csv file with user names and passwords as I've mentioned above. I need to read the csv file and store data in a hash map using open CSV; keys should be Username and password and values should be user1, pwd1...etc.

I'm able to read data from the csv file but not able to get column header (UseName , Password) as keys and data as values to store in hash map. Please see the below code that I tried to do so. I need to know how to get cell values from CSV file (like in excel sheet)

```
@Test
public void dpmethod()throws Exception{
    String csvfile = "C:\\Users....TestData\\LoginData.csv";
    CSVReader  reader= new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvfile));

    try {
        String[] cell; 
        Map<Object, Object> datamap = new HashMap<Object,Object>();  
        while((cell =reader.readNext())!=null) {
            for( int i=0; i<cell.length;i++ ) {
                System.out.println(cell[i]);
                //datamap.put(Key, value );
            }

         }
       }
       catch(NullPointerException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache's Common CSV library:

[image]

The method *[getHeaderMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html#getHeaderMap--)* retrieves the header names.

Maven link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/1.5